# SQL syntax error with mysqli_query in PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this PHP code

```
mysqli_query($connessione,$SCRIPTSQL."\\".$specie."\\LOAD_DATA_AGGIORNAMENTO_limbo_bdn_".$specie.".sql")
```

: I use this code to execute the query (see it below)

where `$connessione` (= connection to DB), `$SCRIPTSQL` (= Windows path, with `\\`) and `$specie` (= variable on my code).

The query is

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\script\\BDN\\caricaDelta\\appoggio\\CAPI_BOVINI_appoggio.lst' INTO TABLE limbo_bdn_capi_bovini
(@var1)
SET
CODICE_USL=SUBSTR(@var1,1,4),
CODICE_DISTRETTO=SUBSTR(@var1,5,2),
ID_ALLEVAMENTO=SUBSTR(@var1,7,13),
DATA_ESTRAZIONE_DATI=str_to_date(SUBSTR(@var1,20,8),'%d%m%Y'),
INSERIMENTO_O_VARIAZIONE=SUBSTR(@var1,28,1),
CODICE_INTERNO=SUBSTR(@var1,29,13),
CODICE_IDENTIFICATIVO_DEL_CAPO=SUBSTR(@var1,42,14),
CODICE_AZIENDA=SUBSTR(@var1,56,8),
IDENTIFICATIVO_FISCALE_ALLEVAM=SUBSTR(@var1,64,16),
SPECIE_ALLEVATA=SUBSTR(@var1,80,4),
FLAG_INSEMINAZIONE=SUBSTR(@var1,84,1),
CODICE_MARCHIO_DELLA_MADRE=SUBSTR(@var1,85,14),
CODICE_ASSEGNATO_IN_PRECEDENZA=SUBSTR(@var1,99,14),
CODICE_ELETTRONICO=SUBSTR(@var1,113,16),
RAZZA_CAPO=SUBSTR(@var1,129,4),
SESSO_CAPO=SUBSTR(@var1,133,1),
DATA_NASCITA_CAPO=str_to_date(SUBSTR(@var1,134,8),'%d%m%Y'),
DATA_INGRESSO_STALLA=str_to_date(SUBSTR(@var1,142,8),'%d%m%Y'),
DATA_APPLICMARCA=str_to_date(SUBSTR(@var1,150,8),'%d%m%Y'),
DATA_ISCRIZ_ANAGRAFE=str_to_date(SUBSTR(@var1,158,8),'%d%m%Y'),
ORIGINE_DELLANIMALE=SUBSTR(@var1,166,1),
PAESE_DI_PROVENIENZA=SUBSTR(@var1,167,2),
CODICE_LIBRO_GENEALOGICO=SUBSTR(@var1,169,3),
DATA_ULTIMO_AGGIOR=str_to_date(SUBSTR(@var1,172,8),'%d%m%Y'),
NUMERO_DI_RIFERIMENTO_DEL_CERTIFICATO=SUBSTR(@var1,180,21),
NUMERO_DI_RIFERIMENTO_LOCALE=SUBSTR(@var1,201,20),
CODICE_MADRE_GENETICA=SUBSTR(@var1,221,16),
STATO_DI_ORIGINE=SUBSTR(@var1,237,2),
FILLER=SUBSTR(@var1,239,2)
```

When I execute the file.php with this query's command, I've got this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'C:\script\BDN\caricaDelta\script\Query_creazione_BDN\capi_bovini\LOAD_DATA_AGGIO' at line 1
```

But if I copy the query code in my client DB (I use Heidi SQL), it's work very good!

Have you got any idea to solve this error?

Thanks, progmr

Comment: Try replacing the double backslashes with a single forward slash in the path to your file and also the INFILE

Comment: @RiggsFolly : thank you for your answer.

1) If I replace the path in PHP syntax, I've got PHP syntax error
2) If I replace the INFILE path, the query doesn't work even in Heidi

Comment: You had better show us what you did. Edit your question and add the code you have got now

Comment: @RiggsFolly

This suggestion _"replacing the double backslashes with a single forward slash in the path to your file"_ doesn't work because. I receive the error `PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR)`

This suggestion _"Try replacing in the INFILE path"_ doesn't work: I've got this `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'C:\script\BDN\caricaDelta\script\Query_creazione_BDN\capi_bovini\LOAD_DATA_AGGIO' at line 1`.  Also, it doesn't work in Heidi SQL client!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I resolve the problem: **mysqli_query doesn't accept a path in its second parameter**. Thank you for your support